# Jasmine does not add our .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instially I add `gem "jasmine"` this line in gem file and i execute this two cmds

- `bundle`
- `rails generate jasmine:install`

its work fine. what my problem is, my `testing.js` file does not add in to the jasmine file.

```
describe("Hello world", function() {
  it("says hello", function() {
    expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

its my code, and my .js file located in public/javascript/testing.js

```
function helloWorld() {
  return "Hello world!";
}
```

The error message is

> ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined in `http://localhost:8888/__spec__/tesfing_spec.js` (line 4)

I added the path in jasmine.yml file as

```
src_files:
  - "public/javascript/testing.js"
```

even though it's not working. Thank you for your answers.